# Get curl php blacklist whoer.net

Tags: php, curl

I have a php code as follows......

```
$result1 = k_curl("http://whoer.net/",$ip);
preg_match('#Blacklist:\n</dt>\n<d(.*?)>\n<span class="ico-holder main-good"> </span>\n<span class="cont">\n(.*?)\n</span>#',$result1, $i);
```

I want to take paragraph Blacklist: No or Yes, but I can only take in blacklist No, I think I was wrong in the regular expression. You can help me to them Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use htmldom ([http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net))
you can optimize this code, but this will do the trick

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("http://whoer.net/");
$array_result=array();
$array_result_data=array();
foreach($html->find('dl.ping') as $element){
    foreach($element->find('dt') as $inelement){
       array_push($array_result,trim($inelement->innertext));
    }
    foreach($element->find('dd') as $inelement){
       array_push($array_result_data,trim($inelement->innertext));
    }
}
//view data saved
$i=0;
foreach ($array_result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.$array_result_data[$i].'<br />';
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an XPath instead of regex.. this will capture yes and no and anything else they'd write in there

```
<?php 
$html=file_get_contents('http://whoer.net');
$domd=@DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
$xp=new DOMXpath($domd);
$res=$xp->query('//*[@id="content"]/div[1]/div/div[2]/dl/dd[5]/span[2]');
$res=$res->item(0);
$res=$res->textContent;
$res=trim($res);
var_dump($res);
```